# DataGrid ComboBoxColumn combo box is not visibe

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have created a data grid combo box, however until the datagrid Combo box  is clicked it acts like a textbox.

How can I permanently show the down arrow in the data grid combo box so the user knows it is a Combo box.

```
<DataGrid Name="DataGridPerson" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name" />
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn  x:Name="ComboBoxGender" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Gender}" Header="Gender"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> People = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    public ObservableCollection<string> Genders = new ObservableCollection<string> { "Male", "Female" };
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataGridPerson.ItemsSource = GetPeople();
        ComboBoxGender.ItemsSource = Genders;
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Person> GetPeople()
    {
        People.Add(new Person()
        {
            Name = "Jane Doe",
            Gender = "Female"
        });

        return People;
    }
}
public class Person{

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty easily by using a TemplateColumn instead and place a Combobox inside:

```
          <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox></ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Although you might have to bind the Items of the combobox in a different way...